# How do I op myself in Minecraft 1.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have started a server in 1.5 and was wondering how to op myself. The `/op <player>` command does not work and in 1.4.7. I used to open up the ops.txt file but I cannot find it in 1.5. Can anyone help as this would be useful to teleport my friend to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the `/op <player>` command and editing `ops.txt` file method still work in both 1.4.7 and 1.5. If the file does not exist, make a new file named that, and put your user name in it.

Please note that the `op <player>` command should be typed on the server, NOT IN THE GAME. If you try to type that in the actual game, you will get an error saying you do not have permission to use this command (because you are not yet an OP).

Comment: There's no slash if it's in the console, as the console automatically adds a `/` at the beginning for you

Comment: Where hould i put the new ops.txt file, and what do you mean by typing the command into the  server.

Comment: Yes, I thought this was what was going on.  Are you trying to use `/op <your nick>` from the game?  That won't work because you are not an op yet.  In the folder where the server executable is run, there is an ops.txt file (or should be) that lists the usernames of those players who have op status.  The first op (i.e. you) must be named by the admin of the server (also you) using either `op <player>` from the server console (outside of the game) or using the `ops.txt` file.

Comment: @mrminecraft3000: Huh? If you downloaded the vanilla server for windows, it should just be `Minecraft_Server.exe` and nothing else.  Run the exe, and it should create a world folder, and a bunch of files, including `ops.txt` in that same directory.  In the window for the executable, there's a stats pane, a players pane, and a log pane.  Below the log is a edit box to enter commands.  This is where you would enter `op <player>`.  If you are not using the vanilla server, tell us now, or we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played around with 1.5 yet, but I believe there were two ways to add users.

- `op <player>` - Typed on the console of the server
- op.txt - You could always try adding the file yourself, making sure to restart the server afterwards.