# How do I become OP on my minecraft server? It won't let me!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So, I have a Minecraft server. However, I can't do anything like commands and stuff so... how do I?

I can't do any commands! I can place and break blocks etc. just not commands and since I'm the owner I kind of need to!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I op myself in Minecraft 1.5?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108767/how-do-i-op-myself-in-minecraft-1-5)

Answer (score 5):

Type `op [username]` into the actual server console (so not the in-game console, in the command window that your server runs in).

Comment: imulsion im using the cmd start. It says **unknown command** please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `op [username]` in the console (window that run.bat opens), without slashes or anything else before this.